# Im implementing Microsoft Azure oauth2 on our web app, but when fetching access token using auth code, we are seeing below error

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-web-app-service

{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.\r\nTrace ID: 1740a160-8c95-42da-aa37-562693c30300\r\nCorrelation ID: 918e8299-271d-46a9-9e9b-5893a348f934\r\nTimestamp: 2022-01-24 11:49:44Z",
"error_codes": [
9002313
],
"timestamp": "2022-01-24 11:49:44Z",
"trace_id": "1740a160-8c95-42da-aa37-562693c30300",
"correlation_id": "918e8299-271d-46a9-9e9b-5893a348f934",
"error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=9002313"
}

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question is too specific, not formatted well and not meeting SO guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

If you are trying to get get token using [`OAuth 2.0 code grant flow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code), then Request access token using authorization code.

[image]

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTennatId.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=YourClentId&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read
```

**Use the authorization code to request an access token:**

```
Token Request Endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenantId/oauth2/token

client_id:YourClientId
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite.All
redirect_uri:https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback
grant_type:authorization_code
client_secret:YourAppsSecret
code:Paste Your Code Here
```

**Post Man Format:**

[image]

**Solution 2:**

After you app registration in the Azure Portal,
[image]

enter this link in the browser to get the code:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
client_id={your-client-id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://localhost:4500/web/completeoauth/ms
&response_mode=query
&state=12345
```

and use postman to get the access token like below:

[image]